# How can I detect logically equivalent filters for DirectorySearcher?

Tags: c#, ldap

The `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` class uses a simple string for it's `Filter` property, so I can have two different strings which are not equal to each other but which will perform logically in the exact same way.  Is there a built-in way to determine logical equivalency?  If not, has anyone tackled this before?

Explanation:  I am using `DirectorySearcher` to return relevant data from Active Directory based on a filter supplied by the user.  I'm counting objects and attributes, and trying to streamline the whole thing by keeping aggregate values to preclude executing the same query more than once.

Here's a simple example of two filters for the `DirectorySearcher` which are logically equivalent but not testable by comparing strings:

```
"(&(objectClass=computer)(|(location=*)(!(department=*))))"
"(&(objectClass=computer)(|(!(department=*))(location=*)))"
```

I would like a way to say `FilterA.LogicallyEquals(FilterB)`.

Comment: You are essentially talking about the first few phases of compiler construction here. It's not something you can throw together in a single function in a few hours.

Comment: I don't know of any library that exposes a service to parse an LDAP query string into an AST.

Comment: Just an idea here, use a regex to extract each english name (`objectClass`, `computer`, `department`, `location`), and the results, and produce a *possible* match if two queries have the same set of words and the same results.  It can have false positives, but might be sufficient.

Comment: I'm using regex's now.  The GUI constrains possible filters to certain forms, so I don't have to solve the general case.  Still, I was hoping not to reinvent the wheel if someone had played with this before.